# Paypal recurring payment initial amount and recurring payment going at a time

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

I am working on paypal API and the initial amount is less than recurring payment. But problem is at time of first payment both initial and recurring amount is deducted from buyer's account. Recurring amount must be deducted from next billing cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "initial amount" on a recurring payments profile will indeed be taken immediately.  This is a separate, one-time payment that occurs when the profile is created.  If the profile itself is scheduled to start on that same day, then yes, both payments would come out at the same time.

Sounds like maybe you're trying to setup a trial period..??  If that's the case there are specific fields for that in the [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) request.

Again, though, the initial amount is separate from the recurring payments.  An example would be signing up for a cable service where you might pay a $100 setup fee (initial amount), $30/mo the first 6 months (trial amount/period), and then $50/mo there-after (regular amount/period).

The $100 setup fee and the first month's $30 would come out that first day.